# Filter function, if data does not fulfil criteria, prompt error

Tags: excel, vba, exception

This is for a textbox after update. It will only filter if there's a value more than 0. However, I can't seem to find out where to add that it prompts an error message if a value is keyed in but cannot be found in the filter range

```
If tbAC.TextLength > 0 Then
    AGCN = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="AGC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=AGCN, Criteria1:=tbAC
    'Assuming that I'm supposed to add a line of code here, smth along the line of if criteria:="" 
    'Msgbox "Invalid Input"
ElseIf tbAC.TextLength = 0 Then
    tbAC = ""
End If
```

Success edit!

```
Private Sub tbAC_AfterUpdate()
Dim AGCN As Long
Dim AGCL As String
Dim Namef As Range

AGCN = Rows("1:1").Find(what:="AGC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
AGCL = Split(Cells(1, AGCN).Address, "$")(1)


If tbAC.TextLength > 0 Then
    'Set Namef = Range(AGCL:AGCL).Find(tbAC)
    Set Namef = Range(AGCL & ":" & AGCL).Find(tbAC)
    If Namef Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid Input")
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=AGCN, Criteria1:=tbAC
    End If
ElseIf tbAC.TextLength = 0 Then
    tbAC = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the use of `tbAC = tbAC`? It's like saying 1=1, there is no point and nothing changes

Comment: @TimStack you're right, I should remove that. For this code, tbAC is numerical, where (example)136 is a criteria that exists. Am trying to input a line of code where the user did input a value, but the value cannot be found in my filter range

Comment: A simple `.Find` to check if the value's present in the range before you execute the autofilter should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Variant`Variable for `AgentCodeN` and use `Application.Match` like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim AgentCodeN As Variant

    If tbAC.TextLength > 0 Then
        tbAC = tbAC
        AgentCodeN = Application.Match(Rows("1:1"), "AGC", 0)
        If Not IsError(AgentCodeN) Then
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter field:=AGCN, Criteria1:=tbAC
        'Assuming that I'm supposed to add a line of code here, smth along the line of if criteria:=""
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Input"
        End If
    ElseIf tbAC.TextLength = 0 Then
        tbAC = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

I don't know if you declared your variables but using `Option Explicit` will force you to do so.

Comment: I've initially declared this as Long as it's a numerical column number. As with my existing codes, an error message does not pop out if i key in wrong data, but rather the sheet just displays empty rows

Comment: @Valwrie empty rows as in, there is no data except for the headers?

Comment: @Valwrie your problem is that you are filtering on the field `AGCN` and you should filter the field `AgentCodeN`

Comment: @Damian I've noticed, have edited the post again to correct those values and the invalid text still doesn't pop

Comment: Your code looks for "AGC", if AGC is there, it won't ever show an error message @Valwrie

Comment: @Damian have posted up an update of what I've tried again with all the corrections